# Extract private keys from Bitcoin Wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, blockchain.info, import

I have encrypted my bitcoin wallet. I know the passphrase, that's not the issue.

I want to transfer my bitcoins to blockchain.info but it's asking me for the private key. I cannot find it nor can I find how to find it. I have searched around on google; a few sites say that pywallet will extract the private key, but I have used this and all I get is the address I have created.

Where is my private key(s)?

Comment: Is it important for you to keep your old addresses? Otherwise it might be simpler to just send the bitcoins to a new address that you generate at blockchain.info.

Comment: Welcome to the site! By the way, I'm wondering if it's just coincidence that the three people involved with this question are Danny, D.H., and me (Daniel H.).

Comment: @D.H. That is true, and I thought of that, but there are transaction fees, waiting, and lack of anonymity involved with that which aren't involved with simply importing the keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [pywallet](https://github.com/joric/pywallet) to extract the private keys and copy the output to [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info)'s Import Backup page.

To use pywallet, you open a command prompt/terminal window at the folder where you saved it and type `./pywallet --dumpwallet --password="Whatever your passphrase is"`. NOTE: this will output everything in plain text, so if you do this on a public computer or with somebody looking over your shoulder, some of your bitcoins may be stolen.

Comment: I did that but its saying pywallet.py: error: no such option: --password

Comment: I was using a different one to the one you gave its doing something now ill post an update if it works, Thanks

Comment: That worked i had to create a bat to dump to a file

Comment: So you have everything uploaded now?

Comment: I just installed pywallet: In Mountain Lion I get the error "no module names _bsddb" ... Do you have any suggestions?